# Plupload: Select files button doesn't work when it is inside a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plupload

The [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) 'Select files' button doesn't work when it's inside a [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

**The problem**

The problem seems to exist on Apple devices only such as the iPad and iPhone. I've tested on a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini running Android 4.2.2 and on a Nexus 7 tablet running Android 4.4.2 and both of those devices work.

**Demo**

Here's a demo to illustrate the problem (note you'll need to view on a iPad or iPhone in order to see the problem):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gyqk9xg3/)

**Notes**

Interestingly, if I move the following mark-up outside of the `.modal` element so that the 'Select files' button is visible on the initial page load, then the problem goes away.

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a>
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
</div>
```

**My question**

How can I get the 'Select files' button working inside the modal for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: I believe the button would not make any sense on iphone because you dont get access to local filesstem, so there would be nothing to upload

Comment: Access to the local file system is possible on iPhone actually.

Comment: Right ;) tested the example on plupload. Can you debug this? Maybe in the ios simulator?

Comment: Might perhaps be due to the fact that the modal element is initially hidden …? Try initializing the Plupload when the modal contents are made visible (I’m sure bootstrap has a callback function for that or something).

Comment: @CBroe Bootstrap does have this `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {  })` which I've tried but I don't think I'm using it right. Can you show me how?

Comment: Just try and put all the code you currently have in your fiddle inside that `function`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PLupload has issues rendering inside initially hidden elements. You should 'refresh' plupload after the dialog is shown.
Add this code right after `uploader.init()`

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    uploader.refresh();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done that (see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyqk9xg3/2/). I'll write back as soon as I've had a chance to test on an iPhone and iPad

Comment: This works with Remodal ( https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal ) as well!